# Java Portlet like functionality with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, portlet

Is there a solution to make a system in Spring MVC with a portlet like functionality?
I mean here to make a system where you can make portlet like plugins in jar or war files, deploy to application (and server) and load them into a jsp, like portlets, separately.
(I no want to use any portlet container implementation)

Comment: You can implement your own *portlet-like* functionality without portlet container (key concept is [cross-context] INCLUDE dispatch). Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604033/is-including-other-jsp-via-the-spring-mvc-framework-a-good-idea .

Comment: I'd like to load dynamically the "portlets". Is it possible to  write an implementation that loads sources which aren't in spring mvc webapp?